# How do I get the path to the Cloud SDK directory using the gcloud command?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

The [Google App Engine Maven Plugin](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/using-maven) requires specifying where the Google Cloud SDK is located if it is not installed in the default location.

```
mvn appengine:deploy -DcloudSdkPath="WHAT_TO_PUT_HERE?"
```

Is there a way to get the location of the Google Cloud SDK from the `gcloud` command-line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can see that `gcloud info` provides this information as `Installation Root: [/Users/username/google-cloud-sdk]`.

To get this information in a useful way, the [`gcloud` command provides a global format option](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/formats). Use `gcloud --format=json info` to see that there is a dictionary `installation` which contains the key `sdk_root` pointing to the correct value.

Next, use the `value` format with a "projection" pointing to this value to just get the SDK root path.

```
$ gcloud --format='value(installation.sdk_root)' info
/Users/username/google-cloud-sdk
```

To use this for the App Engine Maven Plugin,

```
mvn appengine:deploy -DcloudSdkPath="$(gcloud --format='value(installation.sdk_root)' info)"
```